# How to track time spend on website?

Tags: browser, clock

Is there a way to track how much time I spend on a website? So far I've only known about app usage tracking, which tracks the time I open and quit apps. I want to do that with websites as well. Maybe a browser with time tracking can do this.

Comment: How is this in anyway related to Android?

Comment: You can use Android secret code *#*#4636#*#* to track the usage time of browsers but not specific sites

Comment: @Rexford because I use an Android?